# Message trace, Message tracking for all Distribution Groups

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2016

could anyone assist in what command i would need to input i assume it will be a Get-MessageTrackinglog etc

to output to CSV results for any e-mail sent or received from all Distribution Groups within a 6 month period say from todays date.